# rayrender package in r

Tags: r

Trying to install package: 'rayrender' for a project. Have read through the documentation, but have little familiarity with some Github source packages.
I have R Studio Version 2023.03.1+446 (2023.03.1+446), and on MacOS Monterey if that is applicable. Any direction would be helpful.
I am running into this error with Makevars having a missing separator consistently after trying installing:

```
Installing package into ‘/Users/ck/Library/R/x86_64/4.1/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package ‘rayrender’ ...
** using staged installation
/Users/ck/.R/Makevars:4: *** missing separator.  Stop.
/Users/ck/.R/Makevars:4: *** missing separator.  Stop.
/Users/ck/.R/Makevars:4: *** missing separator.  Stop.
/Users/ck/.R/Makevars:4: *** missing separator.  Stop.
/Users/ck/.R/Makevars:4: *** missing separator.  Stop.
/Users/ck/.R/Makevars:4: *** missing separator.  Stop.
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether the compiler supports GNU C... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to enable C11 features... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for g++... g++
checking whether the compiler supports GNU C++... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking for g++ option to enable C++11 features... none needed
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking for X... libraries /usr/X11/lib, headers /usr/X11/include
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating src/Makevars

  --------------------------------------------------
  Configuration for  

    cppflags:  -D RAY_REPRODUCE_PERLIN -DSTRICT_R_HEADERS -DRAY_HAS_X11
    libs:      -L/usr/X11/lib -lX11 
    includes:  -I/usr/X11/include -I/opt/X11/include

  --------------------------------------------------

** libs
/Users/ck/.R/Makevars:4: *** missing separator.  Stop.
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘rayrender’
* removing ‘/Users/ck/Library/R/x86_64/4.1/library/rayrender’
Warning messages:
1: In i.p(...) : installation of package ‘vctrs’ had non-zero exit status
2: In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘RcppArmadillo’ had non-zero exit status
3: In i.p(...) : installation of package ‘terra’ had non-zero exit status
4: In i.p(...) : installation of package ‘sp’ had non-zero exit status
5: In i.p(...) : installation of package ‘vctrs’ had non-zero exit status
6: In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘RcppArmadillo’ had non-zero exit status
7: In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘/var/folders/tq/n679w1k97j731rm5mwt1sq240000gn/T//Rtmpt146dm/file17d015d008827/rayimage_0.9.1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
8: In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘/var/folders/tq/n679w1k97j731rm5mwt1sq240000gn/T//Rtmpt146dm/file17d012c333a1e/rayrender_0.29.6.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

I tried installing via github as seen above. It hit zero exit status, I do not have much experience using github sourced packages.